# Is there a short-hand or relative link-to in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I'm working out an idea in Ember that has some pretty deeply nested routes.

Lets say my route is `simulator.scenario.alien-invasion.situation.in-the-woods.something-else.etc`

Is the only way to get to that route, to:

```
{{$link-to 'simulator.scenario.alien-invasion.situation.in-the-woods.something-else.etc'}}
  <span>Next</span>
{{/link-to}}
```

Or is there some way to know that I'm already "in the woods?" and then have the route relative in some way?

(I'm not really going to have a route this deep, but it brought up the question. : )

Comment: Why dont you use `if` to determine that you are already in the same route, else use `#link-to`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `resetNamespace`.

Quoting the documentation: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html#method_map

> resetNamespace: false by default; when nesting routes, ember will
>   combine the route names to form the fully-qualified route name, which
>   is used with {{link-to}} or manually transitioning to routes. Setting
>   resetNamespace: true will cause the route not to inherit from its
>   parent route's names. This is handy for resources which can be
>   accessed in multiple places as well as preventing extremely long route
>   names. Keep in mind that the actual URL path behavior is still
>   retained.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.route('simulator', function() {
    this.route('scenario', function() {
      this.route('alien-invasion', function() {
        this.route('situation', function() {
          this.route('in-the-woods', { resetNamespace: true } function() {
            this.route('something-else');
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

You should then be able to use relative links like:

```
{{#link-to "in-the-woods.something-else"}}Link Name{{/link-to}}
```

Regardless of where you are.

This is a very helpful talk about route nesting:
http://alexspeller.com/embercamp-london-talk-routing/

Comment: This is unbelievably helpful. In many more ways than answering my specific question. Alex talks fast. I had to put it on .5 youTube speed for the first time ever. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is. [The documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_link-to) is comprehensive for this, and it makes no mention. Glancing through the link-to component code and following it back to the router doesn't indicate it either.

Comment: : ( Hmmmm  I wonder if there is a way to alias it somewhere like a variable.